# Restructure hierarchical data in a REST callout

Tags: json, rest, data, deserialize

I found contact data as JSON on the web that is not organized as the Contact sObject as the phone number is being stored as hierarchical data: please see https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ for the structure.

```
contacts:   
0:  
id: "c200"
name:   "Ravi Tamada"
email:  "ravi@gmail.com"
address:    "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country"
gender: "male"
phone:  
mobile: "+91 0000000000"
home:   "00 000000"
office: "00 000000"
```

This is the callout for the data:

```
public static HttpResponse makeCallout() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        // Cast the values in the 'contacts' key as a list
        List<Object> contacts = (List<Object>) results.get('contacts');
        System.debug('Received the following contacts:');
        for (Object contact: contacts) {
            System.debug(contact);
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

In the for loop I now can define the object Contact and assign values from the object. For the hierarchical data, would I write the following code:

```
Contact cont = new Contact();
cont.phone = contact.phone.home; ?
```

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Create a `List<Contact>` and you can populate the equivalent fields one-by-one with the for loop.

You could see the phone structure and setup the Contact record like this:

```
List<Contact> sfContacts = new List<Contact>();
for (Object contact: contacts) {
    Contact newCont = new Contact();
    newCont.MobilePhone = contact.get('phone').get('mobile');
    // etc...
    sfContacts.add(newCont);
}

insert sfContacts;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, that is the answer I needed!

Comment: Hi I get an error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type Object"!

Comment: I just read that accessing properties in objects is not possible in Apex. Read https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135891/can-we-access-class-properties-dynamically-with-object-class. So there must be a different solution to the problem of accessing hierarchical data?

Comment: Try another `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` on the `contact.get('phone')`.  The whole structure you linked is all JSON, so you should be able to deserialize all the way down

Comment: I think you can also just type case it to `Map<String, Object>`, like: `newContact.MobilePhone = ((Map<String, Object>)contact.get('phone')).get('mobile');`

Comment: Hi Brian, I get the same error. As mentioned, I think that you cannot do a get on an object that is not an sObject...

Comment: Is there any other solution how I can transform hierarchical json into an sobject Contact?

Comment: Not sure.  I suggest editing and updating your question with your attempted solutions (and their errors) so the community has a better chance of helping you