# How do we implement a custom put() method for a wrapper class in APEX?

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, dynamic-apex

I'm looking to create a generic wrapper APEX class with few property fields (`string` type for now). Here is what my class would look like:

```
public class wCustomWrapper {
    public String customProp1;
    public String customProp2;
    public String customProp3;
    ... (this property list could extend to 100 odd properties) ...
}
```

I have consumed this in a method where I'm trying to populate the `customProp1`, `customProp2`, ... field values.

In that method, I'm now looking to make this dynamic like populating as sObject fields, where I could just do `sObject.put(fieldName, value)`, instead of hard referencing each property individually.

Can this be done in any way for a wrapper class?

Comment: Check this questions - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135891/can-we-access-class-properties-dynamically-with-object-class/ there might be some helpful ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one generic `put` method to work, you basically have two options. The first would be to tuck your attributes in a `Map`.

```
public class MyWrapper
{
    public Map<String, Object> attributes;
    public MyWrapper put(String key, Object value)
    {
        attributes.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The other approach would be to use one giant `switch` statement. Probably not worth the effort, as it doesn't scale well and you'd have to update it every time you add a property.

```
public MyWrapper put(String key, Object value)
{
    switch on key
    {
        when 'field1' { attribute1 = value; }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, when I see code similarly structured I would just pass in the `SObject` instance and set all relevant fields at once. If the wrapper represents just one object, usually in the constructor.

```
public class MyWrapper
{
    public MyWrapper(MyObject__c record)
    {
        attribute1 = record.Field1__c;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think I could use `sObject` instance as the response I'm trapping in wrapper is a JSON External API Response. And have similar thoughts like yours on the other approach of using `Map` variable within the class.

Comment: I didn't say you'd put it as an attribute, but rather a parameter in the constructor. You wouldn't change your wrapper structure using that approach.

Comment: Thnx. Yes I misunderstood earlier. Seems much friendlier approach like that. Gonna use it now :-)